# F5 authentication using kerberos keytab

Tags: authentication, f5-big-ip, kerberos, tacacs+

Our network gear use tacplus for authentication and authorization. tac itself authenticates using kerberos. For one of the projects we need automated login to a F5 device using a script. Does anyone know if it is possible for the script to generate a kerberos ticket using keytab and then use the ticket to authenticate via tac/kdc. If possible, can you please point to relevant documentation/links? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, at a minimum, you would need to use another F5 outfitted with Access Policy Manager to achieve the automated login. The F5 is Linux based however, and you might conisider just using an [SSH key to do this](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can authenticate client traffic to a virtual server using Kerberos:

Manual Chapter: Configuring Kerberos Delegation
https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm_implementation/sol_kerberos_delegation.html

You cannot use kerberos for admin system authentication though.  Here are the supported admin auth methods:

Manual Chapter: Configuring Remote User Authentication and Authorization
https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/tmos-implementations-11-3-0/26.html

Local admin database
LDAP 
Active Directory
TACACS+
Client SSL certificate / LDAP

What protocol do you want to use for your admin scripts (SSH or iControl)?

Aaron

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.